# Keep child tags when I get text content with DOM in Java

Tags: java, xml, dom, tags

I am writing an XML generator in Java and I have a structure like that (I simplify it for the example):

```
<autocue>
     <sentence>
          <illustration>smile.jpg</illustration>
          <text>I am a <color red="255" green="0" blue="0">sentence</color> <italic>text</italic>.</text>
     </sentence>
</autocue>
```

I parse this kind of XML file and I works well, but when I use `getTextContent()` on my text node, it gives me a string like that:

```
I am a sentence text.
```

It seems logical. However, I need it to return me a string like that:

```
I am a <color red="255" green="0" blue="0">sentence</color> <italic>text</italic>.
```

Is there a simple way to get that result? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using `getTextContent()` you can use the following:

For the exact node:

```
getElementsByTagName("text").item(0).getNodeValue()
```

But if you have muliple nodes for `autocue`, then you can use the following:

```
NodeList autocueNodes = myDoc.getElementsByTagName("autocue");//here myDoc is the reference for getting document for the parser
    for (int i = 0; i < autocueNodes.getLength(); i++) {
        NodeList autocueChildNodes = autocueNodes.item(i).getChildNodes();
        if (autocueChildNodes.item(i).getLocalName() != null
                && autocueChildNodes.item(i).getLocalName().equals("sentence")) {
            NodeList sentenceList = autocueChildNodes.item(i).getChildNodes();
            for (int j = 0; j < sentenceList.getLength(); j++) {
                if (sentenceList.item(j).getLocalName() != null
                        && sentenceList.item(j).getLocalName()
                                .equals("text")) {
                    String text = sentenceList.item(j).getNodeValue();
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: And what should I do with the NodeList? If I scan it and get the text of each node, I will get the same result, no? Should I add tags to my string manually?

Comment: That I gave for only the exact node. For multiple nodes, you can use the loop for node list. Check edited answer